# How to get the description of a permission of Azure AD roles by Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is it possible to get the description of a permission of **Azure AD roles** by Microsoft Graph API? For example, in Azure portal, I can see that permission `microsoft.directory/applications/owners/read` is described by *Read owners on all types of applications.*.

Is it possible to fetch this mapping by API/SDK?

[image]

Here Azure AD roles refer the role provided by Azure Active directory([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After checking various classes/methods in graph Service client SDK, I figured out that using `ResourceNamespaces`, all the resource actions with description can be fetched using below line of code.

```
var resourceActions =
     await graphServiceClient
    .RoleManagement
    .Directory
    .ResourceNamespaces["microsoft.directory"]
    .ResourceActions
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```